# Is there a FluentNHibernate provider for Active Directory?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, active-directory, poco

I would like to use FluentNHibernate to map an Active Directory user object to a POCO object but can't find a provider in the FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db namespace that will allow me to setup the connection. This is the data layer of a WCF RIA Service. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You will need to implement your own NHibernate `Driver` to accomplish this.